# Accessing type T in Foo<T>

Tags: typescript

Consider a `type foo = Observable<[String, Number]>`

How do I extract `[String, Number]` from it? Such that `type bar == [String, Number]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TypeScript 2.8 and up, you can accomplish this via [type inference in conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#type-inference-in-conditional-types).  The syntax is like this:

```
type InferObservable<T> = T extends Observable<infer U> ? U : never;
```

And try it:

```
type foo = Observable<[String, Number]>
type bar = InferObservable<foo>; // inspects as [String, Number]
```

Hope that helps; good luck!